# Problems with Sinatra + Mustache in OSX Lion

Tags: ruby, macos, sinatra, osx-lion, mustache

I am trying to get up and running with Sinatra and Mustache in OSX Lion. After a lot of googling around I am no further in fixing the issue. I am pretty sure it has to do with Ruby permissions in OSX because the error (below) starts with the first line of the example config.ru file (require 'app'). The project is here ( https://github.com/defunkt/mustache-sinatra-example)

here is my error

```
Boot Error

Something went wrong while loading config.ru

LoadError: no such file to load -- app

/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
config.ru:1:in `block in inner_app'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `inner_app'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:112:in `eval'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:112:in `inner_app'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:102:in `assemble_app'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:86:in `proceed_as_child'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:31:in `call!'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/loader.rb:18:in `call'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/shotgun-0.9/lib/shotgun/favicon.rb:12:in `call'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:134:in `call'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rack-1.3.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/ghostandthemachine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ruby 1.9.2 current dir isn't searched for `require`d files, so you should specify path

```
require './app'
```

Similarly, in `app.rb` you will need to change

`6` `require 'views/layout'` to `require './views/layout'`

and

`9` `:views     => 'views',` to `:views     => './views',`

Comment: hmm... I have made that change in the configure.ru

Comment: It worked for me, but I've made another edit in `app.rb` itself, where I had to change `require 'views/layout'` to `require './views/layout'`

Comment: ah ha, got it! After cleaning up rvm and updating to 1.9.2, then making sure everything was like you said above, I am up and running. Not sure why it didn't work when I was in 1.9.2 before, but whatever. Thanks again

Comment: @JonRose This was helpful. Thank-you for contributing!

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
require 'app'
```

to

```
require './app'
```

It looks like you're using Ruby 1.9.2. The current directory was removed from Ruby's load path in this version, so `require 'app'` no longer works, you need to specify that the file is in the current directory with `require './app'`. I assume that example project was built using an earlier version of Ruby.